# Не использовать SSL-соединение для конкретного домена

Tags: nginx, https, ssl

Имеется хостинг, на нем несколько доменных имен. Для каждого домена устанавливается SSL-соединение следующим образом:

```
if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://$host/$1 permanent;
}
```

Все работает. Но среди доменов появился новый, например, испанский, и мне нужно именно для него использовать обычное http-соединение. Сделал следующее:

```
set $domain_conn_type "https";
if ( $host = "name.domain.es" ) {
        set $domain_conn_type "http";
}
if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $domain_conn_type://$host/$1 permanent;
}
```

Условие не срабатывает похоже. Насколько я понимаю, переменная $host точно должна нести в себе наименование домена. Как мне отловить именно "name.domain.es" по полному совпадению имени? Или, возможно, эта задачу нужно решать вовсе как-то по-другому?

Comment: Подскажите плз (на всякий случай), а это общий nginx-конфиг для всех доменов, или в конфиге для каждого домена дублируется rewrite на https?

Comment: @jekaby все верно, этот конфиг в единственном экземпляре (nginx.conf)

Comment: Лично я просто прописываю перенаправление для каждого домена отдельно. Ещё при изменении и проверке конфигов рекомендую убедиться в отсутствии HSTS (или includeSubDomains в нём), чтобы не оказалось, что перенаправляет не nginx, а браузер сам по себе.

Comment: @andreymal как быть в случае, если домены создаются динамически? число этих доменов и их имена заранее неизвестны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set $domain_conn_type "https";
if ( $host = "name.domain.es" ) {
        break;
}
if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $domain_conn_type://$host/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: он также продолжает не реагировать, перенаправляет на https (

Comment: @MatveySafronov хз, у меня работает такой конфиг. Может, браузер продолжает редиректить? (он же запоминает 301 редирект). Попробуйте curl-запросом.. А вообще, лучше, как советуют, отдельный конфиг на каждый домен, где и прописать редирект по необходимости..

Comment: оо.. с помощью curl я получил html, хотя в mozilla и chrome ответа нет. большое спасибо, не думал что оно запоминает. вот это уже интересно! )

Answer (score 4):

возможно, не стоит «усложнять себе жизнь», а написать попроще:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dom.ru dom.su ...;
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name dom.es;
  ...
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name dom.ru;
  ...
}

...
```

Comment: Зачем, ну зачем все пишут `rewrite` - когда достаточно `return`?!

Comment: @PavelMayorov, привычка, сэр. у меня в хозяйстве имеется, например, вполне работоспособная версия nginx, которая [так не умеет](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return).

Answer (score 3):

Не надо проверять схему if-ами! Надо использовать раздельные директивы server.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 301 https://$host/$uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name name.example.es;

  include "main.conf";
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;

  # Сюда бы добавить настройки ssl

  include "main.conf";
}
```

Comment: спасибо, учту на будущее. сейчас, к сожалению, такой возможности нет, там целый огород конфигов. все это дело на продакшне, и я боюсь что-то поломать, в силу некомпетентности в nginx